# How to post large number of data using requests.post in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have written a sample python code to post log data to Fluntd endpoint of EFK stack. When I send 400 logs at a time, status_code is 200 and can see all the logs at Kibana Dashboard, But when I send 500 logs at a time, the status_code is 414.

Here is the sample python code:

```
import sys
import json
from datetime import datetime
import random
import requests

f = open('/etc/td-agent/data2.json',)
data = json.load(f)

input = file(sys.argv[-1])

actions = []

url = ''
u_name = ''
p_word = ''

for line in input:
    temp = json.loads(line)
    tenantid = temp['HTTP_FLUENT_TAG']
    message = temp['message']
    message_json = json.loads(message)
    h_name = data['account_details'][tenantid]['hostname']
    u_name = data['account_details'][tenantid]['username']
    p_word = data['account_details'][tenantid]['password']
    url = 'https://' + h_name
    for element in message_json:
        temp = str(element['date'])
        url = url + '?time=' + temp
        action = {
                    "msg": element['log'],
                    "id": element['ID']
        }
        actions.append(action)

r = requests.post(url, auth=(u_name, p_word), json=actions)
print(r.status_code)

f.close()
```

Can anyone please help how to send huge load at a time at the Fluentd endpoint.

For Elasticsearch endpoint, we can use the elasticsearch api and it has also bulk feature, which helps to send huge amount of data at a time. I am looking for if there is any such way for Fluentd Endpoint.

Comment: Could you create a json file and send it in the request?

Comment: @Omkar, Do I need to create a separate json file and then write all the action in that json  and after that post it in the request ?

Comment: @triptest_1212 There are two ways this can be done, either there are two ways, 1. create a JSON file of request body jsons and zip them to send them all in a single request, 2. call APIs multiple times with maximum possible jsons as you mentioned above

Comment: @Omkar The first option seems to more feasible for my case, I need to send huge loads like 600,000 logs, calling APIs multiple times can take a lot of time, where the first option with single request can take lesser time.

Comment: @triptest_1212 Sure. I will add this as an answer, could you please accept that as an answer?

Comment: @Omkar I don't see how it will change the behavior because I am also creating a json object and appending in it and posting it a single request.

Comment: @triptest_1212 Earlier you were sending the data as a request body, but now the request body is a type of file that is being sent, in a zip format. Zipping would reduce the size of data, and also, the stream which is created is different. Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways this can be done, either there are two ways.

1. create a JSON file of request body JSON objects and zip them to send them all in a single request
2. Call APIs multiple times with maximum possible JSONs as you mentioned above.